# When did the cosmic event first occur in Coherence?

Tags: plot-explanation, coherence

In the movie [**Coherence**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2866360/), when Halleys comet passes near to Earth...

> the person who tries to cross the dark zone will end up in a random dimension (or parallel universe). Chances of returning to one's own dimension are slim to none as the probabilities are one in millions.

We, the audience still don't know whether the above is just an assumption or the fact about the cosmic anomaly.

I'm just confused about when the anomaly actually started to occur. Did it happen even before Em (the lead character) reached the party?

If that is a yes, does it mean everyone except Lee, Beth and Mike were from different dimensions?

Comment: First off, for a lower budget character movie, this was great.  But I don't believe they ever named the comet, did they?  Anyway, from what I recall, it all started when the power went out.  So they were all together at first.  Then things became jumbled when they saw and went to the other house with power (being their house in another dimension/time/whatever). With each crossing, getting more and more jumbled.

Comment: Without watching the film again ... fairly early, a character is introduced as part of the cast of the series Roswell, although the actor playing the role is not in the cast of "our" Roswell.  Even aside from any in-jokes, in context this suggests the movie begins in a universe other than our own.  While not definitive, in narrative terms I think it suggests the anomaly is ongoing.

Comment: @professor_feather You're right, and I now recall that even at the very start of the film, Em was on the phone with Kevin and she had reception issues, so my guess is that it happened before she arrived, and before some of the other arrived, so they started out already mixed up.  See script [here](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=coherence) at the very beginning for their phone call.

Answer (score 2):

So, as you have hinted in the question - Em faces a phone shatter that is as she's pulling in. It is quite possible that she's already crossed over to another reality right her.

Here's some conversational elements that would support this theory:

Laurie & Kevin used to date, but he doesn't appear to have any recollection of her at all when she's being discussed before she arrives. Meaning, in the reality that Kevin is from, she may have been not as important a figure in his life as for some of the others.

Also, Mike says that he was the main character of Roswell. Laurie, who was apparently a huge fan, fails to recollect him being on the show. Again, this could be because the reality that Laurie is from Kevin wasn't on that show.

(Although this is not mentioned in the film, the actor who played Mike, Nicholas Brendon, was on a the TV show - Buffy The Vampire Slayer. So even for our reality, Mike made a different TV show :))